# click handler for one button stops working due to change in click handler for another button

Tags: jquery

***UPDATE: it was a missing `)` and I've indicated the location in the comments below***

I have a page with a single button with the id `#createButton` and several buttons with the class `.testButton`.

I have a click handler for `#createButton` and another click handler for `.testButton`.

For some reason, when I add a code block to my click handler for `#createButton`, the click handler for `.testButton` stops working. I've indicated the specific code block with comments, below.

Why does the click handler for one button stop working due to changes in the click handler for another type of button please?

```
$(document).on('click','#createButton',function(e){

    if(invalidated == 0 && filledEmbeds > 0){           

        //this code block is causing the problem
        $('.embedContainer').each(function(i, obj) {

        } //Update I was missing a closing paranthesis ) here.

        //some code

    }

    e.preventDefault();
});


$(document).on('click','.testButton',function(e){

        //some code

        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Update: adding HTML below:

```
<div id='embedContainer1' class='embedContainer'>
<textarea name='textareaName[]' id='textareaEmbed1' class='textareaEmbed'></textarea >
</div>
<button class='button testButton' id='testButton1'>Test code</button>


<div class='row item'>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Create" id="createButton">
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your html

Comment: Probably, you get a syntax error, and JS stops execution. Any errors in your console?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Fantastic catch. It was indeed a syntax error and all it needed was checking the console. Thanks for the reminder!!

Comment: What do you do inside  $('.embedContainer').each(function(i, obj) { } ?

Comment: @kajyr I'm still working on that part -- I'm trying to identify if it contains a certain element or not, and if it doesn't contain a certain element, then I'm adding that element to it.

Comment: @user1883050 my solution below, does it help you?

Comment: I see it working --> https://jsfiddle.net/kajyr/tw511erh/, with the ) this is fixed?

Comment: @italyb -- it's fixed, thanks!

Comment: @kajyr -- it's fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the closing `);` after the 'each' operation.
I've just add an alerts to make sure these handlers are fired up

```
$(document).on('click','#createButton',function(e){
        alert("A");
    if(invalidated == 0 && filledEmbeds > 0){           

        //this code block is causing the problem
        $('.embedContainer').each(function(i, obj) {

        });

        //some code

    }

    e.preventDefault();
});


$(document).on('click','.testButton',function(e){
                alert("B");
        //some code

        e.preventDefault();
});
```

adding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmzdgfr9/)

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you should be using the standard selector and add onClick callbacks.

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){});
```

This way of doing it like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.testButton',function(e){});
```

you are binding to the `document` element. When you register it again it will simply override the first event handler on the `document` elment.

Comment: maybe the elements are live-loaded or not always present

Comment: @kajyr that is correct, some buttons are dynamically loaded.